# How do I add typings to a multiple-file/es-style-imports javascript repo?

Tags: typescript, typescript-typings

**TL;DR**: we want one typings file for the multiple files in the repo

---

We have an internal javascript library we're trying to add types to. This javascript library is does not bundle it's files so they are imported like so:

```
import someModule from '@org/some/module/path';
import otherModule from '@org/some/module/other';
```

So far we've had success by creating a typings declaration file (`typings.d.ts`) and putting this file at the root of our typescript project:

`typings.d.ts`

```
declare module '@org/some/module/path' {
  export default function someModule(): string;
}

declare module '@org/some/module/other' {
  export default function otherModule(): string;
}
```

BUT since we're getting a bit more serious with TypeScript, we're looking to move this typings file to that library (instead of in the repo that imports the library) so that those typings can live in that library's repo and be re-used in future typescript projects.

---

What I've tried is moving the `typings.d.ts` file to the internal repo and adding the key `"types": "./typings.d.ts"` to the repo's package.json

After publishing the I'm stilling getting the following error:

```
Could not find a declaration file for module '@sift/skipper/components/Loader'
```

---

Am I missing something? Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are out of luck; if you want to make the imports work without special configuration in every project that uses the library, you'll need to create a `.d.ts` file alongside each `.js` file.

Based on my experiments, TypeScript's algorithm to load a project is roughly like this (others feel free to contribute corrections):

1. Load all source files specified by the `files`, `include`, and `exclude` fields and the `types` option in `tsconfig.json`.  For each loaded file, follow `<reference>` directives and attempt to follow module imports using [module resolution](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/module-resolution.html), but if module resolution fails, don't report an error yet.
2. Make a list of all module declarations seen (`declare module "foo" { ... }`).
3. Revisit each module import to associate it with an actual module: if a module declaration was seen, then use it, otherwise if module resolution found a file that is an external module, then use it, otherwise report an error.

(Side note for the curious: this means that if an import in step 1 loads a a non-module file with global declarations, those global declarations remain in effect even if the import ends up associated with a module declaration instead of the file!)

Previously, your `typings.d.ts` file got loaded as one of the source files of the original project.  But now, nothing is forcing the `typings.d.ts` file in the library to be loaded, and module resolution for `'@sift/skipper/components/Loader'` is looking for a `.d.ts` file alongside the `.js` file, and none exists.  The `types` field of `package.json` only comes into play when you load the root of a package (via either an import or the `types` option or `<reference types="..."/>`); it isn't a general way to find type declarations for all submodules of a package.

Your other options (in roughly increasing order of unconventionality) would be to have the main project use `<reference path="..."/>` to the library's `typings.d.ts`, add the library's `typings.d.ts` to the `files` or `include` field of the main project's `tsconfig.json`, or use `typeRoots` and `types` to force the loading of the root of the library package.

Comment: Thanks for the answer! Definitely helped! I found that `import '@sift/skipper/typings';` works (where the library has the file `typings.d.ts` in its root) when I import it at the entry point of my app. I don't hate the way this looks but now I question how unconventional this is. What do you think? How weird is this?

Comment: It's unconventional, but if you're OK with it for your own projects, fine.  TypeScript is designed so that a package can bundle its own type declarations seamlessly by placing the `.d.ts` files alongside the `.js` files and the caller doesn't have to do anything other than the import of the module it actually wants to use.  Many packages do this.  I've never seen another package that expects callers to do a separate import to get type declarations, though I've seen one package (Kendo UI) that expects developers to download the `.d.ts` elsewhere and add it to their project.